# Cannot get simple Android sound test to work

Tags: android

I tried today to make a stupid, simple program that would play an audio file and stop playing it on demand.  I tried launching it and it immediatly FC'd (Died to the point where Android had to kill it).

Here is my LogCat for it:
http://pastebin.us/4051

here is my main activity code: 
http://pastebin.us/4052

My UI is just a text box and two buttons (PlayButton and StopButton).

Can you please help me?

Thank you,
Sam Dodrill

Comment: it looks as though it can't find the resource R.raw.dog_scare.

Comment: i have res/raw/dog_scare.wav in my build tree. I checked the APK and it is indeed in there, do you know what is going on?

Comment: I don't know enough about how R.java is created to tell you authoritatively what the problem is. Perhaps if you'd pastebin R.java also, I might be able to spot what's wrong.

Comment: and how does the int value 0x7f040000 map to the wav file?

Comment: i don't know, afaik the file is auto-genned

Comment: guess I don't have enough Android experience to be of help. hopefully someone with more knowledge can help with this.

Comment: Perhaps there is an error in the audio file. Have you tried a file that you know works in Android?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should move this initialization

```
MediaPlayer sound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.dog_scare);
```

inside your activitie's onResume method? Try this.